# Android 7.1 (API 25) emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to set up an Android 7.1 emulator but I cant find a proper image.
This is my **SDK Manager** configuration:

[image]

When I try to create the AVD I cant select a CPU/ABI; this my **AVD Manager** (as you can see there is only the Android Wear System Image):
[image]

Do I forget something?

Thanks a lot